# Main screen with left and top bars layout

Tags: usability, layout, windows-os, maps

I'm developing an windows desktop application (WPF) and we are using top and left bars to interact with a 3D Map.

My first layout idea is:

[image: Main Scren]

I was thinking of changing the Left Side bar to the right side and reduce size of the top bar. But I'm having some usability problems with this layout...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty broad question, but there a couple of standard fixes for this set up:

### 1. Make the left sidebar resizeable

The left sidebar is a common pattern for users. When confronted with a main panel that can be heavy on information, users often instinctively try to resize the width of the left panel as needed. Be sure to store their adjustments so they hold next time the app is launched.

### 2. Offer full screen

Once the user has the filters and view preferences set for the main panel, they're ready to dive into the information. Allow a quick switch to move all the controls out of view to maximize the viewport.

As for left vs right, it really depends on what your users are comfortable with. Is there another application they use that makes you think right is better? Have they asked for it? I would say that filters on the left is more common in general use, but this seems like a niche product.